# What's the meaning of "get me"?

Tags: expressions

> Seeing her coming out of the darkness like a ghost ship still gets me every time.

I usually see some expressions like *get someone happy/angry*, but what's the meaning of "get someone"?

Comment: *"...... still gets me **scared**."* missing?

Comment: ..... still makes me scared. It is also looking fine.

Comment: It's more like "catches me (off guard)", "impresses/impacts me", "wows me", or "moves me".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A sentence such as *"That scene still gets me every time"* is fine by itself. Your example gives me a mixed feeling of "gets on my nerve", "catches me off guard", or even "takes me by surprise", because it seems to be about a scary movie. It also reminds me of that famous line *"You had me at hello"* in [Jerry Maguire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_Maguire).

To understand simple words in every occasion is one of the most difficult things in language learning. I wasn't even sure if I could find a good definition in any dictionary for this *get* in your sentence. Luckily, I finally found some on the Free Dictionary,

> **[get](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/get)**
>   *v.tr.*
>   **13. c.** To evoke an emotional response or reaction in: *Romantic music really gets me.*
>         **d.** To annoy or irritate: *What got me was his utter lack of initiative.*

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. And The Free Dictionary is also very powerful.

Answer (score 7):

It means it induces a strong emotion. It is not always clear if the emotion is surprise or terror or delight or sadness. "It really gets me when ..." could refer to any strong, unexpected emotion.

Answer (score 2):

According to the context and situation you can supplement: it always gets me in a certain state/nervous/frightened/in a special mood/in a furious state and so on. Such elliptic use, that is self-evident things are omitted, is very frequent in language. Unfortunately "shortenings" in language is no chapter in grammars. But if you observe language carefully you could fill a dictionary with shortenings.